# Return plot in its original position after zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Below is my JavaScript code which plots scatterplot for a given data defined in the `data` array. When I perform zoom on the scatterplot and drag the plot with `mousedown` event the scatteplot moves from the center.

I wonder how to modify my code that after zooming the scatterplot returns into its original position? In current setting I control this behavior with the `reset` button but I wonder how to do it automatically.

The JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zavgo61r/7/) and the d3.js code is pasted below.

```
var data = [{
  centrality: 12,
  density: 15
}, {
  centrality: 14,
  density: 9
}, {
  centrality: 10,
  density: 6
}, {
  centrality: 16,
  density: 7
}, {
  centrality: 8,
  density: 5
}]

var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the range for x axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.centrality;
  })])
  .range([0, width]);

// Set the range for y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.density;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

// Define mean of x axis
var xMean = d3.mean(data, function(d) {
  return d.centrality;
})

// Define mean of y axis
var yMean = d3.mean(data, function(d) {
  return d.density;
})

// Define zoom function event listener
function zoomFunction() {
  var transform = d3.zoomTransform(this);
  d3.select("#map_g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + transform.x + "," + transform.y + ") scale(" + transform.k + ")");
}

// Define zoom behavior
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 5])
  .on("zoom", zoomFunction)

var chart = d3.select('#main')
  .append('svg:svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr("id", "map_g")
  .call(zoom)
  .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity)
  .on("mousedown.zoom", null)
  .on("touchstart.zoom", null)
  .on("touchmove.zoom", null)
  .on("touchend.zoom", null)
  .on('mousedown.drag', null);

var main = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('class', 'main')

// Draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(x)
  //.orient('center')
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickValues([]);

main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + y(yMean) + ')')
  .attr('class', 'main axis date')
  .call(xAxis);

// Draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  //.orient('right')
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickValues([]);

main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(xMean) + ',0)')
  .attr('class', 'main axis date')
  .call(yAxis);

var g = main.append("svg:g");

var circle = g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return x(d.centrality);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.density);
  })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", "black")

// Reset function
function resetted() {
  chart.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}

// Reset button
d3.select("button")
  .on("click", resetted);
```